# Add "new" link in form field of ManyToOne relation

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I am making a form in Symfony, which is derived from an entity with a ManyToOne field.
When rendering, the field appears as a select, but I would like it to have the option to add a new element that is not found.

I have tried to also use CollectionType :: class, but I do not give with the right combination. I'm using Symfony 3.4.27

```
        ->add('type', EntityType::class, [
            'class'=>'AccessBundle:AVContentType',
            'label'=>'Tipo de contenido',
            'choice_label'=>'name',
])
```

I get a select box but I do not have the option to add new elements

Comment: You'll need to work with a `OneToMany` field (not `ManyToOne`), then follow the instructions in the [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html) to be able to add new elements.

Comment: Symfony doesn't have any option right now that you are trying to find, you can manually give a try by using js.

Comment: The ManyToOne relationship is correct, since, for example, the entity that is editing "article", can only have one element in that column "author", the fact is that when creating a new article, I can only assign an author that already exist, what interests me is to be able to assign, from the same window, a new author.